# Unlock problem with HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire, lock-screens

I have a HTC Desire with original OS. I arrive to start the device by pushing Power button.

The screen lights on with HTC start screen (HTC quietly brillant) then the home screen of the telephone is displayed.

There is a first problem because all my widgets and apps on my home screen aren't displayed. Unfortunately, this is not my main problem.

When the telephone is locked, when I want to unlock by push Power button like usual, the keys to the bottom of the telephone light on but the screen stays black ! The telephone is well unlocked because when I try to increase volume there is the sound of that action.

So, I don't understand very well the problem :(.

Someone would have an idea about this problem ? And some advices to fix that ?

Thanks by advance for your help.

Sylvain.

Comment: Just to clarify: When you first boot up, everything works ok (except for widgets not displaying). But when the phone locks (screen blacks out) when you try to unlock the screen doesn't turn back on? Recent problem? or your phone has always been like this?